# C# Dispose(), unsubscribe from events

Tags: c#, events, idisposable, unsubscribe

Is this the right away to call dispose and unsubscribe from events in this context? context_ is used to manage a simple statemachine that we start and stop essentially by creating a new one.

```
class ClassA
{

      StateContext context_;

      void SomeMethod()
      {
         if(context_ != null)
            context_.Dispose();

            context_ = new StateContext();

      }

   class StateContext : IDisposable
   {
        SubClassA()
        {
            //Subscribe to an event
        }   

        void Dispose()
        {
            //unsubscribe to an Event
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No, you are violating the IDisposable contract.  Contract violations require extra attention and heavy commenting.  As long as the class is not public you'll get away with it.

Comment: If actual code really resembles the example code, you can really simply turn `Dispose` into `Unsubscribe`, not implement `IDisposable`, and still have the same behavior without the need of asking "Am I allowed to make methods that do my wanted logic"

Answer (score 3):

A well-behaved object should not require cleanup beyond calling `Dispose`.  If an object subscribes to events from other objects that may outlive it, it must (to be well-behaved) ensure that those events get cleaned up somehow.  This may be done either be using weak events, or by having `Dispose` take care of the event subscriptions.

Note that the term "unmanaged resource" has only minimal relation to the term "unmanaged code", and that **normal events from long-lived objects are unmanaged resources**.  As such, even though events have nothing to do with unmanaged code, it is entirely right and proper to use `IDisposable` to clean them up.  Indeed, I would suggest that such cleanup should be considered obligatory unless some other means exists to ensure cleanup (e.g. events are handled with a weak-event manager, or the object whose event is subscribed won't outlive the subscriber).  WinForms code is often sloppy, on the presumption that event publishers won't outlive subscribers, but that doesn't mean such sloppiness should be considered desirable.

Comment: "normal events from long-lived objects are unmanaged resources" this is incorrect; the reason for the distinction between unmanaged and managed resources is that during finalization, it may not be safe to touch managed resources, as those objects may already have been finalized. It may not be safe to touch the objects we had subscribed to, in order to unsubscribe during finalization. So these should only be unsubscribed when disposing is true.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn: The distinction between managed and unmanaged resources is based upon whether abandonment will result in obligations being ultimately fulfilled (perhaps via finalization), or ultimately unfulfilled.  If an object subscribes to a normal event from a long-lived object, it won't *be* finalized until it unsubscribes or until the long-lived object becomes eligible for finalization.  If the long-lived object never becomes eligible for finalization until the program quits, the event subscriber won't either.

Comment: @supercat does it mean that we shoud override the `Finalize`(which is `~`) in our class, and place the `unsubscribe()` to the 'unmanaged resource' part in [IDisposable Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8#examples) ?

Comment: @joe: Finalize doesn't generally work with events, because the event subscriber won't become eligible for finalization during the lifetime of the event publisher, and after the publisher's dead the subscription will become moot.

Comment: @supercat I get it. So we should always explicitly call `Dispose` to `unsubscribe` when there is a transient subscriber subscribes to a long-live publisher.